# Matching on multiple fields in aggregate MongoDb query not working

Tags: mongodb, match, aggregate, field

> I have the following code that matches on one field in aggregate query and works fine. Notice the second field in the match is commented out here, and this does return records.

```
db.email.aggregate([
   {$match: {
              SentToEmailService: { $eq: true },
           /* Template: {$eq: "notification"}, */
              }},
   {$group: {
      _id: {
             year : { $year : "$SentOn" },        
            month : { $month : "$SentOn" },        
              day : { $dayOfMonth : "$SentOn" },
          Template: "$EmailMessage.TemplateName",
SentToEmailService: "$SentToEmailService"              
        },
      total: { "$sum": 1}
     }
   },
    {$sort: {_id: -1}}],{allowDiskUse: true})
```

Here is the output:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2023,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 20,
        "Template" : "notification",
        "SentToEmailService" : true
    },
    "total" : 9.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2023,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 20,
        "Template" : "complete",
        "SentToEmailService" : true
    },
    "total" : 9.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "year" : 2023,
        "month" : 1,
        "day" : 20,
        "Template" : "complete",
        "SentToEmailService" : true
    },
    "total" : 9.0
}
...
```

However, when I uncomment the second field to narrow my search results it returns zero records.

```
db.email.aggregate([
   {$match: {
              SentToEmailService: { $eq: true },
              Template: {$eq: "notification"},
              }},
   {$group: {
      _id: {
             year : { $year : "$SentOn" },        
            month : { $month : "$SentOn" },        
              day : { $dayOfMonth : "$SentOn" },
          Template: "$EmailMessage.TemplateName",
SentToEmailService: "$SentToEmailService"              
        },
      total: { "$sum": 1}
     }
   },
    {$sort: {_id: -1}}],{allowDiskUse: true})
```

Here is the empty results:

```
Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms
```

So you can see when I attempt matching on only one field it returns records, but adding a second field to match on returns zero records.  What is wrong here?

Comment: The commented line should be `EmailMessage.Template: {$eq: "smiapi-signup-clv-notification"}` ?

Comment: Hi, that did indeed work.  Thx.  So I "redacted" my post to reveal less information. Would you mind updating your comment to contain simply "notification" in the eq: part of the statement?  Thx!  :-)

Comment: Maybe delete the whole question..? The root cause of your question is "a typo", which will get closed anyway if this post get enough traction

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't too far off and someone internally answered this question.  Here is the line that I added to match on the second field.  I guess it was a nested field and I just needed to name it correctly. :-)

```
 "EmailMessage.TemplateName": "notification" },
```